# Is there a way to get the next item in a list by knowing the current item's value?

Tags: python, list, key

```
my_list = ['apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'raspberry']

# I know that I'm always looking for pear.
print 'pear' in my_list # prints True

# I want to be able to get a key by its value.
pear_key = my_list['pear'].key # should be 1

# Print the next item in the list.
print my_list[pear_key + 1] # should print orange
```

I know that `pear` will always be an item in my list (not the position though), and I'm looking for a way to get the value of the next item in that list, either by getting the current key by knowing its value and advancing it by one (like I did in the example above) or by using something like `my_list.next`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try:
    pos = my_list.index('pear')
    print my_list[pos + 1]
    # orange
except IndexError as e:
    pass # original value didn't exist or was end of list, so what's +1 mean?
```

You could of course pre-cache it, by using (think it's probably the itertools pair recipe)

```
from itertools import tee
fst, snd = tee(iter(my_list))
next(snd, None)
d = dict(zip(fst, snd))
```

But then you lose the fact of whether it was in the original list, or just didn't have a logical next value.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
>>> my_list[my_list.index('pear') + 1]
'orange'
```

Note that if this is the last value in the list, you get an exception `IndexError`.

Answer (score 2):

While the simplest solution has been given, if you want to do this on a generic iterator, rather than a list, the simplest answer is to use [`itertools.dropwhile()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
import itertools

def next_after(iterable, value):
    i = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x != value, iterable)
    next(i)
    return next(i)
```

Which can be used like so:

```
>>> next_after(iter(my_list), "pear")
'orange'
```

Do note that this is a slower and less readable solution if you are working on a list. This is simply a note for an alternative situation.

You could also produce a version with more descriptive errors:

```
def next_after(iterable, value):
    i = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x != value, iterable)
    try:
        next(i)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("{} is not in iterable".format(repr(value)))
    try:
        return next(i)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("{} is the last value in iterable".format(repr(value)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `index` over list to find a particular value: -

```
try:
    print my_list[my_list.index('pear') + 1]
except (IndexError, ValueError), e:
    print e
```